# Dimming Secondary Monitors

Tags: windows, windows-7, multiple-monitors

Does anyone know a programmatic way of dimming secondary monitors while keeping the primary display screen fully bright? I have investigated some existing software, but most will only dim all monitors (or only the primary one). I feel like this might be a windows registry modification perhaps. (This would be for the Windows 7 platform) Even if someone could point me towards registry entries that can be modified for screen brightness levels. I think this is handled in the OS and not always in the monitor itself.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms775240.aspx

Use the SetMonitorBrightness API.

Comment: I haven't used a lot of Microsoft API's before. Any chance you could plop a short blip of code or pseudo code for how it would work? I'd greatly appreciate it! (This will probably be marked as answer as soon as I figure out how to write a quick program using it)

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best software-only solution here would be to create a borderless, layered window for each display, that covers the entire display, and set its background color to, say 50% opaque black. How you do this will depend on which toolkit you're using: WPF? Win32? Qt?

Comment: I don't have a toolkit selected yet. I am open to using just about anything (but I would like a software-based solution)

Answer (score 0):

Ben Straub had the same idea as me. I created this in Visual Studio 2010 with VB.NET which may get you started? Some code used from [Codeproject website](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vb/ClickThroughWindows.aspx)

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices


Public Class Form1

Public Enum GWL As Integer
    ExStyle = -20
End Enum

Public Enum WS_EX As Integer
    Transparent = &H20
    Layered = &H80000
End Enum

Public Enum LWA As Integer
    ColorKey = &H1
    Alpha = &H2
End Enum

<DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="GetWindowLong")> _
Public Shared Function GetWindowLong( _
    ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, _
    ByVal nIndex As GWL _
        ) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="SetWindowLong")> _
Public Shared Function SetWindowLong( _
    ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, _
    ByVal nIndex As GWL, _
    ByVal dwNewLong As WS_EX _
        ) As Integer
End Function

<DllImport("user32.dll", _
  EntryPoint:="SetLayeredWindowAttributes")> _
Public Shared Function SetLayeredWindowAttributes( _
    ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, _
    ByVal crKey As Integer, _
    ByVal alpha As Byte, _
    ByVal dwFlags As LWA _
        ) As Boolean
End Function

Private _InitialStyle As Integer

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    _InitialStyle = GetWindowLong(Me.Handle, GWL.ExStyle)
    Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
    Me.BackColor = Color.Black
    Me.Opacity = 0.1 'Range is 0 (Fully see through) to 1 (Fully opaque)
    Me.TopMost = True
    DimScreenByIndex(1) 'use 0, 1, etc depending on which screen you want to dim

    SetWindowLong(Me.Handle, GWL.ExStyle, _InitialStyle Or WS_EX.Layered Or WS_EX.Transparent)
    'Not needed if setting the opacity: SetLayeredWindowAttributes(Me.Handle, 0, 255 * 0.7, LWA.Alpha)

End Sub

Private Sub DimScreenByIndex(ByVal intScn As Integer)
    For intPtr As Integer = Screen.AllScreens.GetLowerBound(0) To Screen.AllScreens.GetUpperBound(0)
        If intPtr = intScn Then
            Me.Top = Screen.AllScreens(intPtr).Bounds.Top
            Me.Left = Screen.AllScreens(intPtr).Bounds.Left
            Me.Height = Screen.AllScreens(intPtr).Bounds.Height()
            Me.Width = Screen.AllScreens(intPtr).Bounds.Width
        End If
    Next
End Sub
End Class
```